# jQuery Animations Causing Page to Crash in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm building a page with a lot of PNGs being animated by jQuery. Everything was fine up until yesterday, when I noticed that the page would crash in Chrome if I left it open for a few minutes. This doesn't always happen, and I haven't had it happen yet in Firefox, Safari or IE9. I've never built anything on this scale before, so I'm not sure where to even start looking.

I'm using jQuery 1.6.1, jQuery scrollTo 1.4.2, and the jQuery UI slider 1.8.16.

You can see the page [here](http://elfortunawe.com/parallax/al-insan/), and my javascript [here](http://elfortunawe.com/parallax/al-insan/js/scripts.js).

Comment: Doesn't crash mine (16.0.899.0 dev on Linux Ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: It works fine +1 for the link

Comment: Blender: I wish I could take credit for the concept, but I'm not the artist, just the guy making it work.

Comment: I'm not surprised it works in Chrome on Ubuntu (what wouldn't work in Chrome on Ubuntu?) I should have specified: Chrome on OSX.

Seriously, though? No one sees any problems? I thought for sure my javascript was bad. Is my Mac just being cranky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my use of setInterval() to loop animations that was causing the problem. I'm not sure about the details, but replacing all the instances of setInterval() with recursive functions using setTimeout() -- that also checked to make sure the animation wasn't already running -- solved the problem.